# Read data from local file and pass as a parameter to hive script

Tags: shell, hive

Tried dropping a partition by reading data from file and passing parameter to shell script which is invoking hive query, but it is not working, here is the code

```
test.sh

temp =`cat output/0000000_0`

hive -f test.hql -hiveconf var=$temp


test.hql

use db1;

ALTER TABLE employee DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION(week_end_d="${hiveconf:var}");
```

Tried running sh script as

sh -x test.sh

Answer (score 0):

Make two files Syed

1)test.sh

write this,

```
temp=$(cat output/0000000_0)

hive -f test.hql -hiveconf var=$temp
```

2) test.hql

```
ALTER TABLE employee DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION(week_end_d='${hiveconf:var}');
```

Then run command

```
sh -x test.sh
```

note- all files should be in same directory .